# PyMySQL, Use EXECUTE are slow when querying large SQL table

Tags: python, mysql-python, pymysql

```
>>>start_time = datetime.now()
>>>self.cursor.execute("SELECT e.emp_no, first_name,last_name, salary from employees e JOIN salaries s on e.emp_no=s.emp_no")
>>>self.cursor.scroll(value=0, mode='absolute')
>>>page_data = self.cursor.fetchmany(100)
>>>end_time = datetime.now()
```

It takes 38 seconds.....

The information of the two tables：

```
mysql> select count(*) from employees;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   300024 |
+----------+
mysql> select count(*) from salaries;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  2844047 |
+----------+
```

However, it only takes 5 seconds to query the same SQL statement using Navicat.

**I found that it consume most time in self.cursor.execute(....), looks like it did a whole table scan?**

Is there any good optimization method to deal with this problem？
thanks!

python version： python 3.6

pymysql version： PyMySQL (0.10.1)

Comment: Do your tables have indexes on the `emp_no` column?

Comment: yes， i have indexes on the emp_no column for both tables.